# How to pass snapshots generated by a Frame Splitter as an input to another class in Java

Tags: java

I am converting a video into frames using a simple Frame splitter code and these are getting stored in a separate folder.

I want to pass these snapshots sequentially to another module (class) for processing. How Can i do this?

---

this is the code of the Frame Splitter:

```
package FrameSplitter;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaListenerAdapter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.event.IVideoPictureEvent;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.Global;
public class FrameSplitter {

public static final double SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 2;

private static final String inputFilename = "C://Sample.mp4";

private static final String outputFilePrefix = "C://snapshots//mysnapshot";

private static int mVideoStreamIndex = -1; 
// Time of last frame write
private static long mLastPtsWrite = Global.NO_PTS;
public static final long MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES =
        (long)(Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND * SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES);



    public static void main(String[] args) {



        IMediaReader mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(inputFilename);
        // stipulate that we want BufferedImages created in BGR 24bit color             space
        mediaReader.setBufferedImageTypeToGenerate(BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);



    mediaReader.addListener(new ImageSnapListener());



    while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null) ;



}


private static class ImageSnapListener extends MediaListenerAdapter {



    public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event) {



        if (event.getStreamIndex() != mVideoStreamIndex) {



            if (mVideoStreamIndex == -1)

                mVideoStreamIndex = event.getStreamIndex();

            else

                return;

        }


        if (mLastPtsWrite == Global.NO_PTS)

            mLastPtsWrite = event.getTimeStamp() - MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES;


        if (event.getTimeStamp() - mLastPtsWrite >=

                MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES) {
            String outputFilename = dumpImageToFile(event.getImage());

            double seconds = ((double) event.getTimeStamp()) /

                Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND;

            System.out.printf(

                    "at elapsed time of %6.3f seconds wrote: %s\n",
                    seconds, outputFilename);
            // update last write time

            mLastPtsWrite += MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES;

        }
    }
    private String dumpImageToFile(BufferedImage image) {
    try{

            String outputFilename = outputFilePrefix +
                 System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(outputFilename));
            return outputFilename;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

}
`

---

this is the code of the module which performs text extraction from images.. i need to pass the snapshots to this module

```
package tessgui;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.PropertyResourceBundle;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Main
{
  private static Hashtable preferences = new Hashtable();
  public static final String TESS_PATH = "TesseractPath";

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    String tesseractPath = "";

    readPreferences();
   // tesseractPath = (String)preferences.get("TesseractPath");
   tesseractPath = "C:/Tesseract-OCR/";
    File tessLog = new File(tesseractPath + "\\tesseract.exe");
    if (tessLog.canWrite())
    {
      System.out.println("Path valid : " + tesseractPath);
  TessFrame tf = new TessFrame(tesseractPath);
  tf.setTitle("Tesseract 1.00 GUI");
  centerOnParent(tf);
  tf.setVisible(true);
}
else
{
  System.out.println("Path valid: " + tesseractPath);
  TessFrame tf = new TessFrame("Enter Valid Tesseract Path");
  centerOnParent(tf);
  tf.setVisible(true);
    }
  }

  public static void readPreferences()
  {
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    Enumeration myEnum = properties.propertyNames();
        while (myEnum.hasMoreElements())
    {
      String key = myEnum.nextElement().toString();
      if (key.startsWith("Pianificatore")) {
        preferences.put(key, properties.getProperty(key));
      }
    }
    try
    {
      PropertyResourceBundle rb = new PropertyResourceBundle(new         FileInputStream("tessgui.properties"));
  myEnum = rb.getKeys();
  while (myEnum.hasMoreElements())
  {
    String key = myEnum.nextElement().toString();
    String value = (String)preferences.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
      preferences.put(key, rb.getString(key));
    }
          }
    }
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
  System.out.println("File not found");
    }
catch (IOException ex1) {}
  }

  public static void centerOnParent(Window window)
  {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    Rectangle r = ge.getMaximumWindowBounds();
    Dimension dim = new Dimension(r.width, r.height);
    Rectangle abounds = window.getBounds();
    window.setLocation((dim.width - abounds.width) / 2, (dim.height - abounds.height) / 2);
  }
    }
```

---

front end of it

```
package tessgui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.accessibility.AccessibleContext;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.ParallelGroup;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.SequentialGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;

public class TessFrame
  extends JFrame
{
  String tesseractPath = "";
  java.util.List<File> selectedFiles;
  private JButton aboutButton;
  private JButton addFileButton;
  private JPanel buttonPanel;
  private JPanel cfgPanel;
  private JButton changePathButton;
  private java.awt.List fileList;
  private JPanel fileListPanel;
  private JLabel jLabel1;
  private JLabel jLabel2;
  private JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
  private JPanel logPanel;
  private JTextArea logTextArea;
  private JLabel outputFileNameLabel;
  private JTextField outputFileNameTextField;
  private JButton quitButton4;
  private JButton removeAllButton;
  private JButton runButton;
  private JTextField tessPathTextField;

  public TessFrame(String tessPath)
  {
    this.selectedFiles = new ArrayList();
    this.tesseractPath = tessPath;
    initComponents();
    this.tessPathTextField.setText(this.tesseractPath);
  }

  private void initComponents()
  {
    this.cfgPanel = new JPanel();
    this.tessPathTextField = new JTextField();
    this.jLabel1 = new JLabel();
    this.changePathButton = new JButton();
    this.outputFileNameLabel = new JLabel();
    this.outputFileNameTextField = new JTextField();
    this.fileListPanel = new JPanel();
    this.fileList = new java.awt.List();
    this.buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    this.runButton = new JButton();
    this.addFileButton = new JButton();
    this.removeAllButton = new JButton();
    this.quitButton4 = new JButton();
    this.aboutButton = new JButton();
    this.jLabel2 = new JLabel();
    this.logPanel = new JPanel();
    this.jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
    this.logTextArea = new JTextArea();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

   this.jLabel1.setText("Tesseract Installation Path");

    this.changePathButton.setText("...");
    this.changePathButton.setToolTipText("Change Tesseract Installation Path");
    this.changePathButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
  {
    TessFrame.this.changePathButtonActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    this.outputFileNameLabel.setText("Output File Name");

this.outputFileNameTextField.setText("= FileName.txt");
this.outputFileNameTextField.setEnabled(false);

GroupLayout cfgPanelLayout = new GroupLayout(this.cfgPanel);
this.cfgPanel.setLayout(cfgPanelLayout);
    cfgPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(cfgPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(cfgPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addGroup(cfgPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(this.jLabel1).addComponent(this.outputFileNameLabel)).addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addGroup(cfgPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false).addComponent(this.outputFileNameTextField).addComponent(this.tessPathTextField, -1, 329, 32767)).addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(this.changePathButton).addContainerGap(34, 32767)));














    cfgPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(cfgPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(cfgPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addGroup(cfgPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(this.jLabel1).addComponent(this.changePathButton).addComponent(this.tessPathTextField, -2, -1, -2)).addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED).addGroup(cfgPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(this.outputFileNameLabel).addComponent(this.outputFileNameTextField, -2, -1, -2)).addContainerGap(20, 32767)));














this.jLabel1.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("tessPathLabel");
    this.changePathButton.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("changePathButton");

GroupLayout fileListPanelLayout = new GroupLayout(this.fileListPanel);
this.fileListPanel.setLayout(fileListPanelLayout);
    fileListPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(fileListPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(this.fileList, -1, 556, 32767));



    fileListPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(fileListPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(this.fileList, -1, 285, 32767));




this.buttonPanel.setBackground(new Color(204, 204, 255));

this.runButton.setText("RUN");
this.runButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
  {
    TessFrame.this.runButtonActionPerformed(evt);
  }
});
this.addFileButton.setText("ADD FILE");
this.addFileButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
  {
    TessFrame.this.addFileButtonActionPerformed(evt);
  }
});
this.removeAllButton.setText("REMOVE ALL");
this.removeAllButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
  {
    TessFrame.this.removeAllButtonActionPerformed(evt);
  }
});
this.quitButton4.setText("QUIT");
this.quitButton4.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
  {
    TessFrame.this.quitButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
  }
});
this.aboutButton.setText("About");
this.aboutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
  {
    TessFrame.this.aboutButtonActionPerformed(evt);
  }
    });
    this.jLabel2.setForeground(new Color(102, 102, 255));
    this.jLabel2.setText("TessGUI-v0-20");

    GroupLayout buttonPanelLayout = new GroupLayout(this.buttonPanel);
    this.buttonPanel.setLayout(buttonPanelLayout);
    buttonPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(buttonPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(buttonPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(this.jLabel2).addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 63, 32767).addComponent(this.runButton).addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(this.addFileButton).addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(this.removeAllButton).addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(this.quitButton4).addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(this.aboutButton).addGap(46, 46, 46)));
















    buttonPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(buttonPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(buttonPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addGroup(buttonPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(buttonPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(this.runButton).addComponent(this.addFileButton).addComponent(this.removeAllButton).addComponent(this.quitButton4).addComponent(this.aboutButton)).addComponent(this.jLabel2)).addContainerGap(-1, 32767)));














this.logTextArea.setColumns(20);
this.logTextArea.setForeground(SystemColor.textInactiveText);
this.logTextArea.setRows(5);
this.jScrollPane1.setViewportView(this.logTextArea);

GroupLayout logPanelLayout = new GroupLayout(this.logPanel);
this.logPanel.setLayout(logPanelLayout);
    logPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(logPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 556, 32767).addGroup(logPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(this.jScrollPane1, -1, 556, 32767)));





    logPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(logPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 160, 32767).addGroup(logPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(this.jScrollPane1, -1, 160, 32767)));






    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(this.logPanel, -1, -1, 32767).addComponent(this.buttonPanel, -1, -1, 32767).addComponent(this.cfgPanel, -1, -1, 32767).addComponent(this.fileListPanel, -1, -1, 32767));






        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(this.cfgPanel, -2, -1, -2).addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(this.fileListPanel, -1, -1, 32767).addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(this.buttonPanel, -2, -1, -2).addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(this.logPanel, -2, -1, -2)));











    pack();
      }

  private void quitButton4ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
  {
    System.exit(0);
  }

  private void addFileButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
  {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

    int x = 0;
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(this.tesseractPath));
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == 0)
    {
  File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();

  this.selectedFiles.add(f);
  updateShowedList();
    }
  }

  private void removeAllButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
  {
    this.selectedFiles.clear();
    updateShowedList();
  }

      private void runButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
  {
    for (File fs : this.selectedFiles)
    {
      String executeCom = this.tesseractPath + "\\tesseract.exe " + fs.getAbsolutePath() + " " + this.tesseractPath + "\\" + fs.getName().subSequence(0, fs.getName().length() - 4) + "";
      System.out.println(" --- " + executeCom);
      try
      {
        this.logTextArea.append("Starting tesseract for: \n" + fs.getName() + "\n");
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCom);
        p.waitFor();
        if (p.exitValue() == 0) {
          this.logTextArea.append("Done: \n" + fs.getName().subSequence(0, fs.getName().length() - 4) + ".txt \n");
    } else {
          this.logTextArea.append("Errors for: \n" + fs.getName().subSequence(0, fs.getName().length() - 4) + ".txt \n");
        }
      }
      catch (InterruptedException ex)
      {
        Logger.getLogger(TessFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
      catch (IOException ex)
  {
    Logger.getLogger(TessFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
    }
  }

  private void aboutButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
  {
    AboutDlg adlg = new AboutDlg(this, true);
    adlg.setVisible(true);
  }

  private void changePathButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
  {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Select Tesseract Path");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(1);
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(this.tesseractPath));
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == 0)
{
      this.tesseractPath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
      this.tessPathTextField.setText(this.tesseractPath);
    }
  }

  private void updateShowedList()
  {
    this.fileList.removeAll();
    for (File fs : this.selectedFiles) {
      this.fileList.add(fs + "");
    }
  }

  private void updateLog()
  {
    String fileLogName = this.tesseractPath + "\\tesseract.log";
    File tessLog = new File(fileLogName);

    String s = "";
    if (tessLog.canRead()) {
  try
  {
    FileReader fRed = new FileReader(fileLogName);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fRed);
    while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
      this.logTextArea.append(s + "\n");
    }
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
    System.err.println("Unable to read from file");
    System.exit(-1);
  }
}
  }
}
```

`

---

Comment: By passing the snapshots to the class. No one can really help you if you don't post any code or tell what you have tried.

Comment: I've included the code now. Please let me know if you can help me with it now.

Comment: Please format the code correctly. Also you should show what you have tried and simplify that code since no one is going to read hundreds of lines to understand what you are asking.